# Maven clean package, error about not found symbol for "Invalid PropertyValueException"

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

By executing a mvn clean package I see a strange maven output:

```
[ERROR] /home/user/Desktop/mycompany/myapp/server/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/representation/rest/RestControllerAdvice.java:[8,38] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class InvalidPropertyValueException
[ERROR]   location: package com.mycompany.myapp.exception
```

So, I searched the row nr. 8 in that class and I found this one

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
```

But, the line which is referred to InvalidPropertyValueException is 2 rows before:

```
import com.mycompany.myapp.exception.InvalidPropertyValueException;
```

And, the strange thing, in the package `com.mycompany.myapp.exception` I didn't found any class or file named `InvalidPropertyValueException`. But Eclipse accept it and present me in the option list. And this class don't generate any error or red line.

Comment: If you don't need it, then simply remove that import.

Comment: First, thank for your reply. Second, no, I never said I don't need. Sure I need, if I delete this row in the same class I see tons and tons of error.

Comment: could it be that `InvalidPropertyValueException` is coming from one of the dependencies? If eclipse doesn't complain it could be that it has an old version of the class in its cache, try refreshing the project (this is the main reason why I stopped using eclipse). Something to try, is to navigate to the class from inside eclipse, to see where it thinks the class is located.

Comment: There are high chances of "com.mycompany.myapp.exception" be a separate project which you might be using in the current project.. If that is the case then one possibility could be that project version of the "com.mycompany.myapp.exception" is updated and you must've forgotten to update pom of your current project.

Comment: I tried just now and I will inform you! (PS, sorry is very slow. It will take several minutes)

Comment: Ok, @Augusto, I navigate to this one, right click, open declaration, and it is opened a class file editor -> Source not found page. Strange, because inside Eclpise I don't see any error in this row. Tht's happens also after a refres! How is possible?

Comment: Ok @Sanket In the pom.xml (both, the main parent pom and also the sub-part of server sub project) I don't see any reference to package or dependencies about com.mycompany and something else.

Comment: Ok, in according with your tip, if you agree we work start now from command line and not from Eclipse. So, starting from the previous error message, what can be the next step? Thank very (very) much to both.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try **maven->update project** this error may go out.

1. On **Project Explorer**, right-click on the parent module
2. select **maven**, then select **Update Project**

Comment: Ok, it is in progress; it is very slow, sorry.

Comment: Ok, Eclipse now uncredibly slow. I closed it and tried by terminal. If I do an mvn clean install I see the same error. No, is not related to this.

Comment: Maven update will clean and reimport classes you defined